# "I ordered us..." vs. "I ordered for us..." vs "I ordered ... for us"

Tags: grammaticality, word-order

I usually use a phrase such as:

> (1) I ordered us a box.

Would it be more correct to say:

> (2) I ordered for us a box.

Or, better still:

> (3) I ordered a box for us.

Example 3 sounds the most correct, but are 1 and 2 improper English or are they perfectly valid in written form?

Comment: #2 sounds a bit central European, say, Yiddish? But it is not standard English. Could be some regionalism too.

Comment: @Mitch, I upvoted your comment, because I think you are correct in your assumptions :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(1) and (3) are equally grammatical, but (2) is ungrammatical. *Order* is a ditransitive verb, which means it can be followed by an indirect and a direct object as in (1), but it is possible to replace the direct object with a prepositional phrase, as in (3).